# Unable to create config file with AppSettings section in local user directory

Tags: c#, oop, configuration-files

I'm able to read from a .config file and write changes back to it when the config file is located in the application directory. I now want to change this because of user permissions and move my .config file to the users/xxx/local directory.
I've already learned you need to change the SectionInformation.AllowExeDefinition property to ConfigurationAllowExeDefinition.MachineToLocalUser
But I'm unable to change this property for the AppSettings Section.

This is how I read from the AppSettings

```
//Read COM Port settings
UIModel_settings.COMport = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("COMPort");
```

This is how I write to the AppSettings

```
System.Configuration.Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoamingAndLocal); 
config.AppSettings.Settings["COMPort"].Value = UIModel_settings.COMport;
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
```

When I run I get the locked error at the Save method:
    ConfigurationSection properties cannot be edited when locked.

Any ideas how to fix this? Or how I can create this file under my local users directory?

Thanks

Zjerre

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Project, do you have a Settings File Item (e.g. Settings.settings)?

If so this will generate a Settings class with a static Default property that you can use to access the appSettings elements.  If not then you could try adding one from the Solution Explorer -> Project ->  Add Item -> Settings File.

```
UIModel_settings.COMport = Settings.Default.COMPort;
```